# Wordpress Loop with Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, wordpress

Hey guys below I have a interesting problem....  I am trying to setup a left and right side post so that I can take things like read more, post date or author and have them be in the col-md-4 and have the title and the post content along with read more be inside the col-md-8

I have a feeling I am going about this pretty strange as I am rusty as hell with my php and wordpress so any help in achieving this would be helpful.  Interesting problem is I have two read more's put in place with one having a display:none  for WHATEVER reason if I remove that my read more's go bonkers on the page.

The code:

```
<?php
                $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=5
                &category=homeposts');
                foreach($myposts as $post) :?>

                <div class="col-md-8" style="background:#000;">
                <h3><a href="<?php echo the_permalink($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo $post->post_title;?>">
                <?php echo $post->post_title ?></a></h3>                        
                <?php echo substr($post->post_content,0,500) ?>
                <a class="btn btn-default" style="display:none;" role="button" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                </div>   
                <div class="col-md-4" style="background:#000;"><a class="btn btn-default" role="button" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Have you got a screenshot of what is going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by `go bonkers`? Looking at the code, your readmore permalinks are called to the current page/post, while the title of the post itself has a `the_permalink` call with a parameter, which doesn't really accept a parameter...

Comment: Not at this time...  I have since reworked some of the code I will post here again if I have more problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
ok so what is wrong with this....

<?php
                $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=5
                &category=homeposts');
                foreach($myposts as $post) :?>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                <h3><a href="<?php echo the_permalink($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo $post->post_title;?>">
                <?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a></h3>                        
                <?php echo $post->the_excerpt; ?>
                <a class="btn btn-default" style="display:none;" role="button" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                </div>   

                <?php endforeach; ?>
```